# jQuery: How can I detect a blur event on all inputs

Tags: jquery, blur, eventhandler

I've been trying things like

```
$(':input').blur(doStuff());
```

and

```
$('*').bind('blur', doStuff());
```

but nothing seems to trigger correctly. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: `$('input, select, button').on('blur', doStuff);`...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/D5z4D/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, blur doesn't bubble, but jQuery sorta fixes that and makes it bubble, but you could still try [**`focusout`**](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) instead as that is an event that actually does bubble.

Secondly, you're calling the callback function, not referencing it, it should be

```
$('*').on('focusout', doStuff);
```

Thirdly, this is a really bad idea, listening for an event that bubbles on all elements in the DOM, you should probably at least just listen on the top most level

```
$(document).on('focusout', doStuff);
```

and even that is not really a very good idea, it would be better to target the elements directly.

Comment: O, thanks. My eyes are blurry.

I need to target all the inputs that the user can change. Is there a better way to do that than just doing (:input)?

Comment: Give those elements a class, and target the class, that's much better than pseudoselectors.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the class is going to be on every input anyway. Just better performance?

Comment: No, if the class is going to be on every single input you might as well just target `$('input')` or whatever you need to target by tagNames